# Let X be a topological space and $f_1, . . . , f_n : X → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let X be a topological space and $f_1, . . . , f_n : X → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Show
that the sum $f_1 + . . . + f_n : X → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

I am not sure how to think of the sum of continuous functions from topological spaces.

Comment: The fuctions take values on $\mathbb{R}$, so you just consider the sum of the images

Comment: The definition of summing functions from any set to $\mathbb{R}$ is pointwise; if we denote $f = f_1 + \ldots + f_n$, then the definition of $f$ states that $f(x) = f_1(x) + \ldots + f_n(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Note that there's literally no structure required for the set $X$ here; all the structure comes from the codomain $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show the result for $n=2$ (i.e. the function $f_{1}+f_{2})$, and then apply induction.

Answer (score 2):

For real-valued functions $f_1,f_2 : X \to \Bbb{R}$, their $ \textbf{pointwise sum}$ $f_1+f_2 : X \to \Bbb{R}$ defined as $(f_1+f_2)(x) = f_1(x)+f_2(x)$. Note that $f_1 + f_2 : X \to \Bbb{R}$ can be expressed as composition of maps $X \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined by
    $$
 x \mapsto \Big(f_1(x),f_2(x)\Big) \mapsto f_1(x) + f_2(x).
 $$
    Since both map are continous functions (the first map $X \to  \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$ is continous because each factor is continous and the addition map $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is continous by usual $\delta-\epsilon$ argument), then $f_1 + f_2$ is continous.